# Add-Update an element in a list in Scheme

Tags: list, lisp, scheme, racket

I have a list in this form '( (1'()) (2 3) (3 4) (4 '()) ) and I want to update it. 
Eg. where the first value int 2 put to the second value 5

and the result will be like this

'( (1'()) (2 5) '(3 4) (4 '()) )

I have smth like that in mind but I have not idea how to implement it..
also I want to insert the result to a global list that I use

> (define (update ls var1 var2)
>
> (equal? (var1 (car (car ls)))  ( ;add element  to list )   (update (cdr ls)
>   var1 var2 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that:

1. There's only one sublist starting with `2` (the one we want to replace)
2. The input is a list of sublists (not quoted lists, like I pointed in my comment)

… Then an easy solution would be to use `map` to create a new list with the update in place:

```
(define lst '((1 '()) (2 3) (3 4) (4 '())))

(map (lambda (e)
       (if (= (car e) 2) ; check if this is the pair we want to update
           (list 2 5)    ; if so, create a new modified sublist
           e))           ; else keep the sublist as it comes
     lst)

=> '((1 '()) (2 5) (3 4) (4 '()))
```

Answer (score 0):

An issue with Oscar's answer is that if you want to use the list as a global variable, you have to pass it along with every function call, or use set! after you generate a whole new list.

A simple table implementation can be found here. http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-22.html#%_sec_3.3.3